# pocketsphinx-android getting 0 for getBestScore() and getProb() methods

Tags: android, pocketsphinx

I'm using pocketsphinx android for development of an application.
Using keyphrase search for activation. Activation works not so good with many false positives and not always recognizing what I say. so I decided to use getProb method to see the probability of detected words but both getBestScore() and getProb() methods always return 0, what can be the cause of that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected. Confidence is returned for individual phrase matches with segments API, there is no confidence for the whole hypothesis in keyword search mode.

Probability is useless for accuracy analysis, instead you should better collect and share raw audio dumps on your device as well as the exact keyword configuration you are using.